# Jetty cannot access org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.*

Tags: java, сервер, jetty

```
Information:Using javac 1.8.0_45 to compile java sources
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'java'
Information:22.04.2016 2:37 - Compilation completed with 5 errors and 9 warnings in 1 sec
Warning:java: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.ManagedObject': class file for org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.ManagedObject not found
Warning:java: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.Name': class file for org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.Name not found
Warning:java: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.Name'
Warning:java: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.ManagedAttribute': class file for org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.ManagedAttribute not found
Warning:java: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.ManagedAttribute'
Warning:java: Cannot find annotation method 'readonly()' in type 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.ManagedAttribute'
Warning:java: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.ManagedObject'
Warning:java: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.ManagedOperation': class file for org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.ManagedOperation not found
Warning:java: Cannot find annotation method 'impact()' in type 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.annotation.ManagedOperation'
E:\JAVAWEB\src\main\java\src\main\Main.java
Error:(13, 16) java: cannot access org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle
  class file for org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle not found
Error:(15, 25) java: cannot access org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPool
  class file for org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPool not found
Error:(16, 15) java: cannot access org.eclipse.jetty.util.Attributes
  class file for org.eclipse.jetty.util.Attributes not found
Error:(18, 15) java: cannot access org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle
  class file for org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle not found
Error:(19, 15) java: cannot access org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Destroyable
  class file for org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Destroyable not found
```

Main.class

```
package main;

import servlets.MirrowServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MirrowServlet allRequestsServlet = new MirrowServlet();

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(allRequestsServlet), "/*");

        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(context);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>java.webproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>new-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.9.M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите вывод `mvn dependency:tree`. Скорее всего вам надо  добавить зависимость

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty-version}</version>
</dependency>
```